# Why is my Haskell selection sort implementation extremely fast?

Tags: performance, sorting, haskell

I implemented selection sort and compared it to Data.List's sort. It is orders of magnitudes faster than Data.List's sort. If I apply it to 10,000 randomly generated numbers the results are as follows:

```
 ✓ in 1.22µs: Selection sort
 ✓ in 9.84ms: Merge sort (Data.List)
```

This can't be right. First I thought maybe merge sort's intermediate results are cached and selection sort uses those to be much faster. Even when I comment out merge sort and only time selection sort, it is this fast however. I also verified the output and it is correctly sorted.

What causes this behaviour?

I use this code to test:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module Lib
    ( testSortingAlgorithms
    ) where

import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Text.Printf
import Control.Exception
import System.CPUTime
import Data.List (sort, sortOn)


selectionSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
selectionSort [] = []
selectionSort nrs = 
  let (smallest, rest) = getSmallest nrs
  in smallest : selectionSort rest
  where getSmallest :: Ord a => [a] -> (a, [a])
        getSmallest [a] = (a, [])
        getSmallest (a:as) = let (smallest, rest) = getSmallest as
                             in if smallest > a then (a, smallest : rest)
                                                else (smallest, a : rest)


main :: IO ()
main = testSortingAlgorithms


testSortingAlgorithms :: IO ()
testSortingAlgorithms = do
    !list' <- list (10000)
    results <- mapM (timeIt list') sorts
    let results' = sortOn fst results
    mapM_ (\(diff, msg) -> printf (msg) (diff::Double)) results'
    return ()


sorts :: Ord a => [(String, [a] -> [a])]
sorts = [
        ("Selection sort", selectionSort)
      , ("Merge sort (Data.List)", sort)
    ]


list :: Int -> IO [Int]
list n = sequence $ replicate n $ randomRIO (-127,127::Int)


timeIt :: (Ord a, Show a) 
       => [a] -> (String, [a] -> [a]) -> IO (Double, [Char])
timeIt vals (name, sorter) = do
    start <- getCPUTime
    --v <- sorter vals `seq` return ()
    let !v = sorter vals
    --putStrLn $ show v
    end   <- getCPUTime
    let (diff, ext) = unit $ (fromIntegral (end - start)) / (10^3)
    let msg = if correct v 
              then (" ✓ in %0.2f" ++ ext ++ ": " ++ name ++ "\n") 
              else (" ✗ in %0.2f" ++ ext ++ ": " ++ name ++ "\n") 
    return (diff, msg)


correct :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
correct [] = True
correct (a:[]) = True
correct (a1:a2:as) = a1 <= a2 && correct (a2:as)


unit :: Double -> (Double, String)
unit v | v < 10^3 = (v, "ns")
       | v < 10^6 = (v / 10^3, "µs")
       | v < 10^9 = (v / 10^6, "ms")
       | otherwise = (v / 10^9, "s")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You write

```
let !v = sorter vals
```

which is "strict", but only to WHNF. So you are only timing how long it takes to find the smallest element of the list, not how long it takes to sort the whole thing. Selection sort starts by doing exactly that, so it is "optimal" for this incorrect benchmark, while mergesort does a bunch more work that's "wasted" if you only look at the first element.

Comment: Aha. So it actually isn't completely sorted? So how do I force a complete strict evaluation? I thought this was how.

Comment: @Arthur perhaps look at the last element `let !v = last $ sorter vals` ?

Comment: I added `let !l = last v` and the timing results look much better now, thanks!

Comment: @Arthur Have you looked at the [`criterion`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) benchmarking library? It manages this subtle trickery with attention. For instance, there is a `nf` function that transforms a value to normal form, evaluating it completely.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov I hadn't but this looks useful. Thank!